# Eclipse+Subversive- Multiple src paths in a single project each from a separate parts of a single repository

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, subversive

In a nutshell, I would like to have a single eclipse project with multiple src directories each managed by subversive (or subclipse).  If the code base were small, I would use several projects.  However, the code base is not small (50+ src paths).  Does anyone know how to do this with the Subversion plugins for eclipse? All of the src paths derive from modules that in turn have a common point node in the repository.  However, the modules are versioned, so I can’t checkout all of them.

It looks as though Subclipse and Subversive do not support multiple src paths.  Can anyone confirm this?

Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using the `svn:externals` property.  I'm not sure if or how this is done specifically with Subclipse, but using the `svn` command line tool you'd do:

`svn propedit svn:externals /my/parent/project`

format that file as such:

```
sub-project-1 https://svn.myserver.com/sub-project-1/trunk
sub-project-2 https://svn.myserver.com/sub-project-2/trunk
```

Although I haven't tried it, I would assume this would work with Eclipse.  When you do an `svn update`, all of these external references will be checked out automatically.

Comment: This works for update and checkout - thank you.

However, the issue still remains that the Project-Build Path src packages are not recognized.  Any ideas with supporting multiple srcs?

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate things: The directories that are source folders, and the versioning. These topics are more or less independent from each other.

There is the `.classpath` file in the project root that defines which directories are source folders. You can add more directories to it using the context menu in eclipse on the respective directories.

Seriously, you have 50+ source paths, each from a different repository? Besides the technical proplems you face with this, I wonder what use case you are following...

Comment: A slight misunderstanding.  I don't have 50+ repositories.  I have 50+ modules all stored in a single repository.  Each module is versioned independently.  The difficulty is in bringing all of these together into a single Eclipse project.  Neither Subversive nor Subclipse seem to work correctly when dealing with partially checked out repositories.

Comment: I see. However, partially checking out a repository is the default case. You usually have a trunk and branches, and you check out only one of them.
I think that you can put all your modules into one directory. So that you have `/trunk/module1`, `/trunk/module2`, ... Then you create an eclipse project for each of the modules, like `/trunk/module1/.project`. You can check out only some modules, or, the default case, the whole trunk. You open eclipse on the trunk and import all the existing projects.